# I have 2 navigational menus (PHP), but I don't know how to erase one without breaking the other in this code:

Tags: wordpress

I have a navigational menu on a WordPress PHP site -- called **Primary Menu**.  I'm trying to override the default navigational menu with the mega menu I created in the widget area I created.

**Here's the problem:**

I'd like to have the menu in the widget area I created, "**my_mega_menu**".  But the     inkthemes_nav() function adds the native theme menu.  When I comment this out, it shows only the menu I want it to show, but it breaks the functionality of the menu; the drop-downs don't drop down into the sub-menus.

Does anybody know if it's possible to eliminate the inkthemes_nav native menu, but maintain the functionality of the mega-menu I created?

[image: Double Menu]

**Here's the code in my header.php:**

```
<div class="menu-bar">
<div id="MainNav">                  
<a href="#" class="mobile_nav closed"><?php _e('Pages Navigation Menu', 'colorway'); 
?><span></span></a>    

<?php inkthemes_nav(); ?>            
<?php /* Widgetized sidebar */
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('my_mega_menu') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>            
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!--End MenuBar-->
</div>
```

If this questions is more appropriate for the wordpress.stackexchange forums, please migrate it ... but I felt it was more of a php-based question.  Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer to point me in the proper direction (what I should be looking for, what to do, etc.)!

Comment: There's nothing in PHP that's remotely problematic here - it's entirely a WordPress API and site design issue.

Comment: Thanks Philip ... I'll delete this and ask in the WordPress forums ...